# Video path is not accessing in android 4.4 when I am going to pic a video from gallery

Tags: android

Hello friends I am using the following code to pic a video from gallery..

```
private static final int SELECT_VIDEO = 3;
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select a video"), SELECT_VIDEO);

On activity result: 

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        try{
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO)
                {
                    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                    videopath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){

            //  MLog.e("On Activity result.", "Error: "+e);

        }
    }

//get path method

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION}; 
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        String filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
        int fileSize = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE));
        long duration = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION)));
    return filePath;
}
```

Now using above code I am getting null for video path in android 4.4. Can any one help me and let me know what should I have to use that I can pic the video from gallery successfully in android 4.4.

Answer (score 0):

> Now using above code I am getting null for video path in android 4.4.

You will get `null` in many cases, but particularly on Android 4.4+. That is because there does not have to be a file that you can access that corresponds to the video. [A `Uri` is not necessarily a `File`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html).

You need to get rid of `getPath()` and use the `Uri` properly. For example, `MediaPlayer` and `VideoView` can work with the `Uri` directly. If you need the bytes of the video, use `openInputStream()` on `ContentProvider` to read in the video.